# Guaranteed robust file copy over network in .net

Tags: .net, distributed, file-copying

It is required per requirements of some specific project to copy comparably large files over the (slow) network. The software which is doing this currently uses File.Copy to do this. Whenever an error occurs during file copy the process just retries File.Copy operation again and again.

Due to the nature of the network and the size of the files passed errors occur during data transfer somewhere in the middle of file copying which requires copying the same data over and over again.

I am thinking of a solution when file is passed in chunks and when a chunk fails to be passed (with checking a checksum preferably) then only this chunk of data is requested again, so that any data data has been already passed and verified is kept. Something like these advanced file downloaders that allow you to download parts of the files if file copying failed in the middle.

I wonder if there are some ready solutions for such purposes.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Though I like your question, it's not on-topic for StackOverflow. It seems you are asking for a library or tool: such questions are specifically off-topic.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that this might be considered as off-topic.
However, this is not the question about specific library, I am asking about the way how this can be achieved without inventing a wheel. I.e. I don't know for example maybe File.Copy itself does chunk validation and retries internally and wondered if anyone could point me to the correct direction.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind switching technologies you could go for FTP transfer, there certainly are libraries for .net too.

FTP allows you to resume transfers.

If you need guaranteed delivery you might think about message queueing (but this won't keep you from resending on failure)

Comment: Unfortunately, FTP is no go here as it will require setting up FTP server on the whole estate of machines that we are supporting which is a little bit of overhead for what we need.

Comment: MSMQ usage is possible, however, MSMQ packet are limited in size and it might be an overhead to use all MSMQ power to just send chunks of data files. It will also require all the chunking/checksum implementation to still be programmed. But I was thinking whether there are some standard approaches to this without writing all the supporting code.

Comment: @AlexeyStolybko  So basically you search a solution (which is off-topic like MicroVirus pointed out) and neither want to do a lot of coding or install software on the servers ? If you want to stick with File.Copy you should show us your code and ask how it can be changed, perhaps this is even a topic for the codereview area of stackexchange.

Comment: However, to  be clear I thought about my question for a while and FTP seems to be something that has been invented specifically for the purpose I need. And if I want something clever to be doing chunking and producing checksum - I need to have some kind of server logic that will be doing this which seems to overlap a lot with what FTP protocol provides. Thanks for the reply